# Graphics.ReleaseHdc() throws ArgumentException error with multi-threaded instances

Tags: c#, image, graphics, argumentexception

I have a game with several enemies, each running in its own thread for movement and drawing. The enemies are drawn on a Panel and thus their threads have to access the Panel's Graphics. I have protected the `CreateGraphics` call using `Lock` and when I want to `ReleaseHdc` the Panel's Graphics I get a *System.ArgumentException*, even though I call the `ReleaseHdc`-method without any arguments.
Here's the relevant code (`p` is the Panel reference passed down as a static variable and points to the correct control):

```
//Member region
internal Bitmap Img = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"Enemy.png"), Size);
internal static readonly object _Lock = new object();

//from enemy's custom Move() method
lock (_Lock)
{
    Graphics gfx = p.CreateGraphics();
    gfx.DrawImage(Img, Location);
    gfx.ReleaseHdc(); // gfx.Dispose() works here                     
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why I get this error and/or how to fix it, considering the multi-thread access that I need to draw every element onto the same panel in its own thread?

**[Edit]**

Using `gfx.Dispose()` instead of `ReleaseHdc()` did the trick.
The result though is not satisfying, because I get a very unstable image with flickering enemys. This is probably a problem from drawing them repeatedly often and not related to my question - or is there a connection between this problem and how I handle the multiple threads?

Comment: You are playing a very dangerous game.  That lock was certainly a good idea, you however did not put that same lock in the panel's OnPaint() method.  Derive your own class from Panel and override OnPaint() and OnPaintBackground().  Using ReleaseHdc() was wrong, you have to use Dispose() instead.  Might work, don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Is there a conflict in creating several instances of a control's `Graphpics`? Can there only be one in existance at the same time, so that it's not possible for every thread to create its own?

I'm reworking my program at the moment to derive from `Panel`, but it would be good to know anyway.

Comment: Creating Graphics instances in multiple threads is fine.  Using its properties like DpiX is fine.  Stuff like MeasureString() is fine.  Actually using them to paint to the screen, that's a dangerous game.  Also very hard to reason what you'll end up with when multiple threads render to the same screen area, the end result is always unpredictable.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this is properly done?
I'm okay with rewriting my program, but right now I have no idea how I can `DrawImage` to a `Panel` from several threads. Or is the secret to draw everything on the panel from the background thread using updated parameters (like Location) from the threads, maybe?

Comment: Boilerplate in gaming code is to render to a back-buffer and to blit it to the screen.  Simple to do by drawing to a bitmap, can be done by a worker thread safely.

Comment: Thanks for the info!
That will teach me how worker threads work, finally. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be calling `gfx.GetHdc()` if you're going to call `gfx.ReleaseHdc()`?

I think your code should look like this:

```
lock (_Lock)
{
    using (var gfx = p.CreateGraphics())
    {
        gfx.DrawImage(Img, Location);
    }
}
```

I also find the call to `CreateGraphics()` in itself is a little suspect. I'd expect the `Graphics` object to be supplied *to* the drawing code rather then created *by* it.

Comment: This still throws the same exception. But see my edit above - using Dispose() works.

Comment: @Johannes But the code I posted above IS using Dispose()! That's what the `using` does... And if it throws the same exception, it implies that the problem isn't with `ReleaseHdc()` since the code I posted doesn't even call it...

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize it and didn't remove the `ReleaseHdc()`! Works exactly like typing in Dispose manually, thanks!

About your other comment: is there a good way to provide the Panel.CreateGraphics to every thread? I guess setting it via static variable and protecting it with the Lock should work? I tried it before very briefly and got an error, so I tried create it this way.

Comment: I redid `CreateGraphics` as a static reference from the main form as you suggested and it works. Sadly no improvement regarding the flickering problem, but much better code to read. ;)

Comment: @Johannes Well for multithreading I guess you need to create the graphics object dynamically like that, since you're not allowed to share it between thread. However if the thread is running in a loop you should be able to create the graphics object once at the start of the thread (but remember to dispose it when the thread exits).